# How to make interceptor Unit tesing

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am trying make interceptor unit testing using below code but i am getting exception please help me some one my code there in stackbliz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-unit-testing-example-xnm226

### interceptor

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
      if (err.status === 401) {
      }
      const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;
      return throwError(error);
    }))
  }
}
```

### test

```
import { TestBed, inject, async } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpClientModule, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AutherizationInterceptor, InterceptorSkipHeader } from './authInterceptors';
import { ErrorInterceptor } from './errorInterceptors';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

describe('ErrorInterceptor', () => {
    let http: HttpTestingController;
    let httpClient: HttpClient;
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpClientModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
            providers: [{
                provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
                useClass: ErrorInterceptor,
                multi: true
            }]
        })
        http = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
        httpClient = TestBed.get(HttpClient);
    });

    it('Error interceptor test', () => {
        httpClient.get(environment.baseUrl + 'api/user/login').subscribe(
            response => {
                expect(response).toBeTruthy();
            }
        );
        http.expectOne(environment.baseUrl + 'api/user/login').error(new ErrorEvent('Unauthorized error'), {
            status: 401
        });
        http.verify();
    });
});
```

Comment: do you get an error if you try to throw the original error instead of a message?

Comment: @Andrei please open my stackbliz link i am not getting some erros

Comment: I am trying to coverage this code since 2 days but no result ,i need some suggestions to finish this

Comment: from your stackblitz I see AutherizationInterceptor failing when you try to set null value to 'Authorization' header.

Comment: now i update please check one

Comment: 2 sceps 0 failures. green tests now

Comment: but code not covered 100% in autherization interceptor and error inteceptr

Comment: In my Vscode same code in autherization interceptor showing error --->AuthHttpInterceptor Authorization interceptor FAILED
        TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Comment: yeah, that is Auth interceptor failing because you are trying to setHeader:{'Authorization': null}

Comment: how do you check coverage on stackblitz?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207330/discussion-between-krish-and-andrei).

Comment: no i am not checking through stackbliz, checking from vscode only

Comment: i am not setting autherization header null  ---->const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json').set('Authorization','token')